# Sending the same PUT request multiple times creates more entries in the database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose, put

As far as I know, with PUT one can create a resource if it doesn't exist or it is going to replace the old one with a new one.

I want to create a resource and being able to update it, not create more resources, using Node.js/Express and MongoDB.

So, I wrote this code:

```
app.put('/entries/:entry_id/type', (req, res) => {
  const entry = new Entry (req.body);
  entry.save();
  res.end();
})
```

in Postman there is a PUT request, having the url: `localhost:5000/entries/2/type`

After sending it once, it creates an entry in the dabatase. All good!

But let's try to send the same request again. Now there are 2 entries in the database. I would expect to be one, because the same request was sent.

In the database they have the same data, same schema but they do have an extra field,
`"_id":{"$oid":"5e8909e60c606c002axxxxxx"},`, which is has the last character different.

Why are there created more entries of the same data while I was expecting to have only one entry in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Mongo automatically creates a [default index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#default-id-index) named `_id` on every collection when it is created. If you insert a Document into a collection without specifying an `_id` it will generate a new `ObjectId` as the `_id` field.

To get around this you can use [`findOneAndUpdate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) with `upsert`:

```js
Entry.findOneAndUpdate({ entry_id: req.params.entry_id }, { <content> }, { upsert: true })
```

However this will update the document if it exists already instead of creating a new one. If you further wish to not change the Document at all if it already exists, then you can surround your `<content>` with [`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/).